# How to include dictionary creation into Run Keywords in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to use combination Run Keywords and Create Dictionary built-in keywords
This code:

```
Run Keywords
...    &{dict}    Create Dictionary    ${data}
```

returns:

> Variable '&{dict}' not found.

any ideas?

message

Comment: ok, and if there is more keywords to run, next keyword will just be on the next line like this:  ...    another keyword?  What about if I want to define another variable on the next line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Run Keyword` specifically designed to be used in setup or tear down methods where creating an user defined keyword is an Overkill. User defined keyword does the same thing as Run Keywords but additionally it can return you the values from the enclosing keywords.

Here is the [`Run Keywords` documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keywords)

Coming to the problem. `Run keyword` will treat any variable argument as keyword unless it is not the parameter of the keyword using `AND` operator. In the error -  `&{dict}` it is searching for the variable but it is not found. hence the error. Following code demonstrate the behavior of `Run keywords`

```
***Variable
${keyword}=    comment something

***Testcase
Test1
    Run Keywords    ${keyword}

***Keyword
comment something
    log    This is comment
```

**Output -**

[image]

Actual resolution -

Define new keyword and enclose the keywords of your requirement and call the user defined keyword.

```
***Keyword
User Defined Keyword    [Arguments]    ${key}   ${value}

    &{dict}=   Create Dictionary     ${key}    ${value}
    Return from keyword    ${dict}


*** Testcase
User Keyword Demo
   &{dict}=    User Defined Keyword    name=xyz
   Log     ${dict}
```

**Output =**

[image]

Comment: What about the situation, when I want to run more steps when the condition is true: for example: 1. define var 2. Log var 3. run keyword 4. define var2 5 run keyword with argument var2

Comment: I don't see anything critical in the above steps. it is straight forward doable.
you can do the conditional execution using `Run Keyword If   '${var2}'!= 'false'    User Defined Keyword`

Comment: ok, I used the similar solution, I hoped, that robot framework is able to use combination -> run keyword if  |  condition  |  run keywords  |  arg=  set variable  |  arg2 = keyword arg | keyword arg2 , but anyway, your solution is applicable.